# OpenGL: finding the normal, unitary vector of a vertex

Tags: opengl

I have an object on which I want to apply lighting. It is described in a text file with its vertex coordinates.

I read the following in the the OpenGL Superbible:

```
void m3dFindNormal(M3DVector3f vNormal, const M3DVector3f vP1, const M3DVector3f vP2, const M3DVector3f vP3);
```

> To use this function, pass it a vector
>   to store the normal, and three vectors
>   (each just an array of three floats)
>   from your polygon or triangle
>   (specified in counterclockwise winding
>   order). Note that this returned normal
>   vector is not necessarily unit length
>   (normalized).

I understand that the order in which I pass the vertices (clockwise or counterclockwise) determines the orientation of the normal vector, so I wonder how can I make the function work with a file of [this format](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/off/off.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, this format looks kind of OBJ-ish, but with colors and without normals and texture coords. Seems like it's not really a good choice! But if you *really* want to stick with it...

My piece of advice no. 0 is:

Use another format, seriously. :) Raw binary dump of vertices (positions+normals+texture coords+colors+whatever) and then indices is the simplest solution usually.  And if you *really* *really* want to use .off...

My piece of advice no. 1 is:

- import it into Blender (write an importer script in Python or use another tool to change the format)
- have Blender calculate the normals for you (it's going to do it well!),
- export it to any format with normals.

If you don't want to (or can't) do that for any reason, there's piece of advice no 2. on how to generate normals yourself:

- for each face, calculate its temporary face-normal (for a face `A,B,C`, it's `(B-A)x(C-B)` ). Don't rescale it to length=1 - the bigger the face's area, the longer the resulting normal vector will be and that's what we want (for now).
- for each vertex, sum all the face-normals from the faces touching that vector (this is where non-normalization of per-face normals comes handy - you'd get some kind of a "weighted sum" with the face area being the weight) and *then* normalize the resulting vector. This is a nice approximation of a per-vertex normal which you can use.

Comment: I can't use another format, this a school assignment. What benefit does using this 'weighted sum' bring?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The weighted sum makes sure that if a vertex is next to a big face and a small face, then the normal will be more slanted toward the bigger one. But that's still a big approximation (but quick to run and to be implemented).

Answer (score 0):

Try it, the order depends on the program that created the .off file, the description of the format doesn't seem to define the normal orientation. I'd just take the order they appear in the index list and pass it to the function. If that doesn't work, pass them in a reverse order.