# Calculating and Applying normals to a triangle mesh

Tags: opengl, 3d, normals

I have a triangle mesh and I'm trying to calculate the normals so I can apply them when drawing the mesh. I'm using immediate mode (will probably change to vertex arrays when I get time to understand how they work) and drawing the mesh with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP.

I am having trouble calculating the vertex normals. More precisely deciding which neighbouring vertices to use in the calculations and then deciding when to set those normals. Consider this:

```
 1_2
 |/|    Supposedly a square where the numbers represent the vertex number in a            
 3 4    triangle strip.
```

I know you have to compute the cross product of 2 vectors belonging to a plane in order to get the plane normal. So in that example the top triangle's normal could be calculated by doing (2-1)x(3-1), and the second one by doing (2-4)x(3-4). How do you then apply the normals when drawing the triangle strip in immediate mode?

What I was doing was setting the first normal when vtx 1 is set, the second when vtx 4 is set, the third when vtx 5 is set, etc. This however gives issues as you obviously end up by having different normals for each of the vertices of a triangle (when they should all be the same). For instance, triangle |2,3,4| would only have vertex 4 with the correct normal (since for vertices 2 and 3 the normal would be the one of the first triangle).

So how should it be done? Is there a way, or do I need to change to `GL_TRIANGLES`? (I don't want to stop using immediate mode for now as I don't have time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm correct you're still only computing a normal per triangle? This is correct, but after that you should computed what the normal is per vertex. This is simply the normalized sum of all triangle normals that the specific vertex is attached to. 
Once completed you can proceed with your immediate mode drawing, specifying a normal per vertex.

Comment: This is correct for interpolated vertex shading.  If you desire to have flat shading you'll need to duplicate shared vertices so that each set of points per face has unique normals and not averages.

Comment: That's right. A weighted sum (with the weight being the triangle's area) also works good AFAIK. See my post on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247994/opengl-finding-the-normal-unitary-vector-of-a-vertex/4248112#4248112

Comment: @Ron Warholic: Ah, I see now how the poster could have meant that. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted. 
@Ron Warholic: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by having duplicate vertices and how would you draw the triangle Strip if you had more than one vertex at the same position (Im guessing thats what you mean by duplicate vertices)

Comment: @Zepee: You can't use triangle strips for flat shading (at least not so they still function as triangle strips); you would just use GL_TRIANGLES.  Notably though, triangle strips do support duplicating vertices (commonly to create degenerate triangles).  This is useful for creating meshes that have features that would otherwise prohibit triangle strips from being used.